# Actionscript three older target not working?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

This code works fine in actionscript 3 when my target is 10.3 and up but when my target is flash player 9, it gives me the error Scene 1,

Layer 'Layer 1', Frame 1, Line 7    1119: Access of possibly undefined property L through a reference with static type Class.

Anyone know how I can fix this so that it works in flash player 9? I already tried changing the keyboard.(keycode#) and even trying it with what is apparently the flash player 9 keycode syntax?
but everything I tried is failing. I cannot find a solution online, anyone got any ideas? thanks

```
var lDown:Boolean = false;
var sDown:Boolean = false;
var dDown:Boolean = false;
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, onKeyBoardDown);
function onKeyBoardDown(e:KeyboardEvent):void
{
if (e.keyCode == Keyboard.L)
{
    lDown = true;
}
if (lDown == true)
{
    if (e.keyCode == Keyboard.S)
    {
        sDown = true;
    }
}
if (sDown == true)
{
    if (e.keyCode == Keyboard.D)
    {
        dDown = true;
    }
}
if (dDown == true)
{
    trace("ehhh");
    }
}
```

Comment: Many regular AS3 features were not present in FP9 like Vector for example. So targeting FP9 might very likely result in a project that cannot be built especially if using custom framework (where the use of Vector is common).

Comment: I don't actually need to build this project, it just needs to be testable so it can run in cs6, it's for shcool

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was intrigued in this question because looking at the documentation, [Keyboard and its constants](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/ui/Keyboard.html#L) are available from Flash Player 9+, however like you have said, I cannot access the constants `A-Z` via `Keyboard` when targeting Flash Player 9. I do however have access to other constants like `F1`, `HOME`, `NUMPAD_*`, etc.

As soon as I change the Flash Player version to 10 or greater, I am able to access the `A-Z` constants.

I have tried to find the reason for this, however at this stage all I can assume is that the documentation is invalid and those constants aren't actually available until Flash Player 10.

Fortunately, a workaround is pretty straightforward in this instance: make your own constants for the character codes for A-Z:

```
package
{
    public class KeyCodes
    {

        public static const A:uint = 65;
        public static const B:uint = 66;
        public static const C:uint = 67;
        public static const D:uint = 68;
        public static const E:uint = 69;
        public static const F:uint = 70;
        public static const G:uint = 71;
        public static const H:uint = 72;
        public static const I:uint = 73;
        public static const J:uint = 74;
        public static const K:uint = 75;
        public static const L:uint = 76;
        public static const M:uint = 77;
        public static const N:uint = 78;
        public static const O:uint = 79;
        public static const P:uint = 80;
        public static const Q:uint = 81;
        public static const R:uint = 82;
        public static const S:uint = 83;
        public static const T:uint = 84;
        public static const U:uint = 85;
        public static const V:uint = 86;
        public static const W:uint = 87;
        public static const X:uint = 88;
        public static const Y:uint = 89;
        public static const Z:uint = 90;

    }
}
```

To use this class, paste the contents into an `.as` file that is in the same directory as your FLA, then:

```
if(e.keyCode == KeyCodes.A) // etc
```

I am in the process of trying to find the exact reason for this.

Comment: Thank you man, it's so nice to see all the helpful people on here.

Comment: Hey, this is going to sound quite noobish but how do I implement this class into a usable fla file? I've tried making a package and everything, I just can't get it working. I wasted almost an hour on this and I was wondering if you could help me out or point me in the right direction thanks.

Comment: @Altrows Oh, I'm sorry - you should have said sooner. I'll update my answer.

Comment: @Altrows There you go.